# How to rename a MySQL column from long to something else

Tags: mysql

I have a database table with a column name as 'long'. It is a keyword of MySQL and not sure whether it is a keyword conflict or something, I cannot run some of the simple SQL script using this keyword-column name. I try to run the SQL to alter the column name, using: `alter table mytable change column long lng double` but it doesn't work.

The question is, what's the reason from prevent the above simple alter SQL from working? (For any other columns on hand, the above SQL works) and how can I make it work if it is a reason of keyword conflict? Is there any keyword escape symbol that I can use in MySQL?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE COLUMN `long` lng DOUBLE
```

(The backtick is, AFAIK, MySQL specific.)

> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. ... The identifier quote character is the backtick ("`") ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html))

Comment: This is the answer I have been asking for. Thanks for the quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a "right quote" around "long"

Like this :

```
`long`
```

Answer (score 1):

try again query working properly alter table table_name change column long lng double but its neccessary the datatype of long should be integer then try may be your problem solved