# MySql insert error for no reason

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `towers_raw_data` (
`DoveID` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`NG` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`SNLat` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`SNLong` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
`Postcode` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`TowerBase` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`County` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`Country` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`ISO3166code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Diocese` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
`Place` varchar(29) DEFAULT NULL,
`Place2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`PlaceCL` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`Dedicn` varchar(54) DEFAULT NULL,
`Bells` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Wt` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`App` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`Note` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Hz` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`Details` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`GF` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Toilet` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`UR` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`PDNo` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`PracN` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
`PSt` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`PrXF` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
`OvhaulYr` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`Contractor` varchar(28) DEFAULT NULL,
`TuneYr` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`ExtraInfo` varchar(163) DEFAULT NULL,
`WebPage` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
`Updated` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Affiliations` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
`AltName` varchar(39) DEFAULT NULL,
`Simulator` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Lat` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
`Long` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`DoveID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And I'm trying to run the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `towers_raw_data` (`Affiliations`, `AltName`, `App`, `Bells`, `Contractor`, `Country`, `County`, `Dedicn`, `Details`, `Diocese`, `DoveID`, `ExtraInfo`, `GF`, `Hz`, `ISO3166code`, `Lat`, `Long `, `NG`, `Note`, `OvhaulYr`, `PDNo`, `PSt`, `Place`, `Place2`, `PlaceCL`, `Postcode`, `PrXF`, `PracN`, `SNLat`, `SNLong`, `Simulator`, `Toilet`, `TowerBase`, `TuneYr`, `UR`, `Updated`, `WebPage`, `Wt`) VALUES
 ('','','','3','','','Leics','S James','C','Leicester','AB KETTLEB','Ringing prohibited; tuning: 1-3 of 4','','879.0','GB','52.79858','-0.92747\r\n','SK724229','A','','','','Ab Kettleby','','','LE14 3HS','','','','','','','6918','','','','','652')
```

For some reason I am getting the following error:

```
  #1054 - Unknown column 'Long ' in 'field list'
```

Anyone know why this is happening when I've clearly got a field called Long in my table

Comment: `Long ` should be `Long` (check out the the actual space in that field name, that is also in the error.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error was generated for a reason.

there is an extra space in your column name `long`,

```
`long ` is not equal to `long`
```

so you should remove the extra trailing space.

Comment: Nice one this was driving me mental!

Comment: @geoffs3310 you should be careful sometimes `:D`

Answer (score 2):

you have a field called "long" not "long "

Notice the trailing space

use

```
INSERT INTO `towers_raw_data` (`Affiliations`, `AltName`, `App`, `Bells`, `Contractor`, `Country`, `County`, `Dedicn`, `Details`, `Diocese`, `DoveID`, `ExtraInfo`, `GF`, `Hz`, `ISO3166code`, `Lat`, `Long`, `NG`, `Note`, `OvhaulYr`, `PDNo`, `PSt`, `Place`, `Place2`, `PlaceCL`, `Postcode`, `PrXF`, `PracN`, `SNLat`, `SNLong`, `Simulator`, `Toilet`, `TowerBase`, `TuneYr`, `UR`, `Updated`, `WebPage`, `Wt`) VALUES
 ('','','','3','','','Leics','S James','C','Leicester','AB KETTLEB','Ringing prohibited; tuning: 1-3 of 4','','879.0','GB','52.79858','-0.92747\r\n','SK724229','A','','','','Ab Kettleby','','','LE14 3HS','','','','','','','6918','','','','','652')
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT refers to `Long` not `Long`
There is a space at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is a keyword in mysql and you may have problems with that column name.

See more info at [How to rename a MySQL column from long to something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243932/how-to-rename-a-mysql-column-from-long-to-something-else)

Comment: yes it's a keyword but in the insert statement, there is an extra trailing space that's why the error says it cannot found the column `long `

Comment: yes, I saw that, my answer is just an addition.

Comment: hes put it in backticks, So this is not an issue.

Comment: I didn't say that's is an issue in this case. I said `you may have problems`